# ansible remote_user as root

Tags: authentication, ssh, ansible

I want to get started with ansible and there is a simple thing I dont get:

```
flipl@sun ~ % ansible -vvvv -m ping t420
SUDO password: 
<t420.beach.lan> ESTABLISH CONNECTION FOR USER: flipl
<t420.beach.lan> REMOTE_MODULE ping
<t420.beach.lan> EXEC ssh -C -tt -vvv -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o ControlPath="/home/flipl/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r" -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o ConnectTimeout=10 t420.beach.lan /bin/sh -c 'mkdir -p $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1454775840.71-251439732457316 && chmod a+rx $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1454775840.71-251439732457316 && echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1454775840.71-251439732457316'
<t420.beach.lan> PUT /tmp/tmp1fqFHM TO /home/flipl/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1454775840.71-251439732457316/ping
<t420.beach.lan> EXEC ssh -C -tt -vvv -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o ControlPath="/home/flipl/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r" -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o ConnectTimeout=10 t420.beach.lan /bin/sh -c 'LANG=C LC_CTYPE=C /usr/bin/python /home/flipl/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1454775840.71-251439732457316/ping; rm -rf /home/flipl/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1454775840.71-251439732457316/ >/dev/null 2>&1'
t420.beach.lan | success >> {
"changed": false, 
"ping": "pong"
}

flipl@sun ~ % su -
Password: 
Last login: Sa Feb  6 17:22:40 CET 2016 on pts/0

[root@sun ~]# ansible -vvvv -m ping t420 -u flipl
SUDO password: 
<t420.beach.lan> ESTABLISH CONNECTION FOR USER: flipl
<t420.beach.lan> REMOTE_MODULE ping
<t420.beach.lan> EXEC ssh -C -tt -vvv -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o ControlPath="/root/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r" -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=flipl -o ConnectTimeout=10 t420.beach.lan /bin/sh -c 'mkdir -p $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1454775858.05-125216053853458 && chmod a+rx $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1454775858.05-125216053853458 && echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1454775858.05-125216053853458'
t420.beach.lan | FAILED => SSH Error: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
while connecting to 192.168.0.100:22
It is sometimes useful to re-run the command using -vvvv, which prints SSH debug output to help diagnose the issue.
```

Do I miss something particular in using ansible?

The aim, I want to achieve, is that only root can execute playbooks (why is there a SUDO Password prompt but it doesnt matter, what I put in there). Due to security, root-access via ssh is not allowed.
So I wanted to play around with executing playbooks/ansible commands as root, using ssh with a client-Login and becoming root again for package installation.

But as you can see, I have already problems with simple tasks :(

I already tried to edit my inventory file:

```
[t420]
flipl@t420.beach.kan
t420.beach.lan ansible_ssh_user=flipl
```

Any help will be apreciated!

thanks,
pwe

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you added your public key to the authorized file in the remote server?

Comment: yes, I did that, but something is strange: 'flipl$ ssh t420' works fine, but 'root# ssh flipl@t420' doesnt work ...

Comment: Probably your root keys are different from user flipl.
Check if they are different you need to add the root key as well to authorized file of remote server.

Comment: as I mentioned, it is not allowed to login as root via ssh, so why do I have to add my root-ssh-key???

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I solved it.

```
root# ssh-copy-id flipl@t420
```

solved it ...

I think, I misunderstood the ssh-key-concept ...